# How to create a JTree with JCheckbox to Show Systems All drives and its Folders/Files

Tags: java, swing, jtree, jcheckbox

I am beginner in java. I am creating a file chooser that can select multiple drives, folders or files at a time for worm scanning purpose. I have written the code to work fine for a single drive (e.g. c:\ or e:\ etc). I am trying to create a tree for all drives in system. Please tell me how to accomplish this.

Code

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.event.*;
    import javax.swing.tree.*;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Vector;

    public class FileTreeDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{                                              
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("cant done"); 
    }
    // Create a JTree and tell it to display our model
    JTree tree = new JTree();

    // The JTree can get big, so allow it to scroll
    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(tree);
    // Figure out where in the filesystem to start displaying       
    File[] roots = File.listRoots();  
    FileTreeModel model = new FileTreeModel(null); 
    model = new FileTreeModel(roots[0]);
    tree.setModel(model);
    CheckTreeManager checkTreeManager = new CheckTreeManager(tree); 
    TreePath checkedPaths[]=checkTreeManager.getSelectionModel().getSelectionPaths();
    int j = checkedPaths.length;
    System.out.println("Tree Path :"+j);
    for(int i=0; i<checkedPaths.length;i++){
    System.out.println("Tree Path :"+checkedPaths[i]);
    }
    // Display it all in a window and make the window appear
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("FileTreeDemo");
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollpane, "Center");
    frame.setSize(400,600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }  
    }


    import java.io.File;
    import javax.swing.event.TreeModelListener;
    import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel;
    import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;
    import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;
    import javax.swing.tree.TreeSelectionModel;

    public class FileTreeModel  extends DefaultTreeSelectionModel implements TreeModel{
    // We specify the root directory when we create the model.

    protected File root;
    public FileTreeModel(File root) { this.root = root; 
    //setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.DISCONTIGUOUS_TREE_SELECTION); 
    }

    // The model knows how to return the root object of the tree
    public Object getRoot() { return root; }

    // Tell JTree whether an object in the tree is a leaf
    public boolean isLeaf(Object node) {  return ((File)node).isFile(); }

    // Tell JTree how many children a node has
    public int getChildCount(Object parent) {
    String[] children = ((File)parent).list();
    if (children == null) return 0;
    return children.length;
    }

    // Fetch any numbered child of a node for the JTree.
    // Our model returns File objects for all nodes in the tree.  The
    // JTree displays these by calling the File.toString() method.
    public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {
    String[] children = ((File)parent).list();
    if ((children == null) || (index >= children.length)) return null;
    return new File((File) parent, children[index]);
    }

    // Figure out a child's position in its parent node.
    public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {
    String[] children = ((File)parent).list();
    if (children == null) return -1;
    String childname = ((File)child).getName();
    for(int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    if (childname.equals(children[i])) return i;
    }
     return -1;
    }

    // This method is invoked by the JTree only for editable trees.  
    // This TreeModel does not allow editing, so we do not implement 
    // this method.  The JTree editable property is false by default.
    public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath path, Object newvalue) {}

    // Since this is not an editable tree model, we never fire any events,
    // so we don't actually have to keep track of interested listeners*/
    public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {}
    public void removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {}
    }


    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
    import javax.swing.plaf.ActionMapUIResource;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    /**
    * Maintenance tip - There were some tricks to getting this code
    * working:
    *
    * 1. You have to overwite addMouseListener() to do nothing
    * 2. You have to add a mouse event on mousePressed by calling
    * super.addMouseListener()
    * 3. You have to replace the UIActionMap for the keyboard event
    * "pressed" with your own one.
    * 4. You have to remove the UIActionMap for the keyboard event
    * "released".
    * 5. You have to grab focus when the next state is entered,
    * otherwise clicking on the component won't get the focus.
    * 6. You have to make a TristateDecorator as a button model that
    * wraps the original button model and does state management.
    */
    public class TristateCheckBox extends JCheckBox{
    private final TristateDecorator model;

    public TristateCheckBox(String text, Icon icon, Boolean initial){
    super(text, icon);
    // Add a listener for when the mouse is pressed
    super.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    grabFocus();
    model.nextState();
    }
    });



    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Component;
    import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JTree;
    import javax.swing.tree.TreeCellRenderer;
    import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

    public class CheckTreeCellRenderer extends JPanel implements TreeCellRenderer{ 
    private CheckTreeSelectionModel selectionModel; 
    private TreeCellRenderer delegate; 
    private TristateCheckBox checkBox = new TristateCheckBox(); 
    public CheckTreeCellRenderer(TreeCellRenderer delegate, CheckTreeSelectionModel selectionModel){ 
    this.delegate = delegate; 
    this.selectionModel = selectionModel; 
    setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
    setOpaque(false); 
    checkBox.setOpaque(false); 
    } 


    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean  selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus){ 
    Component renderer = delegate.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);  
    TreePath path = tree.getPathForRow(row); 
    if(path!=null){ 
    if(selectionModel.isPathSelected(path, true)) 
    checkBox.setState(Boolean.TRUE); 
    else 
    checkBox.setState(selectionModel.isPartiallySelected(path) ? null : Boolean.FALSE); 
    } 
    removeAll(); 
    add(checkBox, BorderLayout.WEST); 
    add(renderer, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
    return this; 
    ![enter image description here][1]} 
    }
    // Reset the keyboard action map
    ActionMap map = new ActionMapUIResource();
    map.put("pressed", new AbstractAction(){      //NOI18N
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    grabFocus();
    model.nextState();
    }
    });
    map.put("released", null);                     //NOI18N
    SwingUtilities.replaceUIActionMap(this, map);
    // set the model to the adapted model
    model = new TristateDecorator(getModel());
    setModel(model);
    setState(initial);
    }

    public TristateCheckBox(String text, Boolean initial){
    this(text, null, initial);
    }

    public TristateCheckBox(String text){
    this(text, null);
    }

    public TristateCheckBox(){
    this(null);
    }

    /** No one may add mouse listeners, not even Swing! */
    public void addMouseListener(MouseListener l){}

    /**
    * Set the new state to either SELECTED, NOT_SELECTED or
    * DONT_CARE.  If state == null, it is treated as DONT_CARE.
    */
    public void setState(Boolean state){
    model.setState(state);
    }

    /** Return the current state, which is determined by the
    * selection status of the model. */
    public Boolean getState(){
    return model.getState();
    }

    /**
    * Exactly which Design Pattern is this?  Is it an Adapter,
    * a Proxy or a Decorator?  In this case, my vote lies with the
    * Decorator, because we are extending functionality and
    * "decorating" the original model with a more powerful model.
    */
    private class TristateDecorator implements ButtonModel{
    private final ButtonModel other;
    private TristateDecorator(ButtonModel other){
    this.other = other;
    }

    private void setState(Boolean state){
    if(state==Boolean.FALSE){
    other.setArmed(false);
    setPressed(false);
    setSelected(false);
    } else if(state==Boolean.TRUE){
    other.setArmed(false);
    setPressed(false);
    setSelected(true);
    }
    else{
    other.setArmed(true);
    setPressed(true);
    setSelected(true);
    }
    }

    /**
    * The current state is embedded in the selection / armed
    * state of the model.
    *
    * We return the SELECTED state when the checkbox is selected
    * but not armed, DONT_CARE state when the checkbox is
    * selected and armed (grey) and NOT_SELECTED when the
    * checkbox is deselected.
    */
    private Boolean getState(){
    if(isSelected() && !isArmed()){
    // normal black tick
    return Boolean.TRUE;
    } else if(isSelected() && isArmed()){
    // don't care grey tick
    return null;
    } else{
    // normal deselected
    return Boolean.FALSE;
    }
    }

    /** We rotate between NOT_SELECTED, SELECTED and DONT_CARE.*/
    private void nextState(){
    Boolean current = getState();
    if(current == Boolean.FALSE){
    setState(Boolean.TRUE);
    } else if(current == Boolean.TRUE){
    setState(null);
    } else if(current == null){
    setState(Boolean.FALSE);
    }
    }

    /** Filter: No one may change the armed status except us. */
    public void setArmed(boolean b){
    }
    public boolean isFocusTraversable() {
    return isEnabled();
    }

    /** We disable focusing on the component when it is not
    * enabled. */
    public void setEnabled(boolean b){
    //            setFocusable(b);
    other.setEnabled(b);
    }


    /** All these methods simply delegate to the "other" model
    * that is being decorated. */
    public boolean isArmed(){return other.isArmed();
    }
    public boolean isSelected(){return other.isSelected();
    }
    public boolean isEnabled(){return other.isEnabled();
    }
    public boolean isPressed(){return other.isPressed();
    }
    public boolean isRollover(){return other.isRollover();
    }
    public void setSelected(boolean b){other.setSelected(b);
    }
    public void setPressed(boolean b){other.setPressed(b);
    }
    public void setRollover(boolean b){other.setRollover(b);
    }
    public void setMnemonic(int key){other.setMnemonic(key);
    }
    public int getMnemonic(){return other.getMnemonic();
    }
    public void setActionCommand(String s){other.setActionCommand(s);
    }
    public String getActionCommand(){return other.getActionCommand();
    }
    public void setGroup(ButtonGroup group){other.setGroup(group);
    }
    public void addActionListener(ActionListener l){other.addActionListener(l);
    }
    public void removeActionListener(ActionListener l){other.removeActionListener(l);
    }
    public void addItemListener(ItemListener l){other.addItemListener(l);
    }
    public void removeItemListener(ItemListener l){other.removeItemListener(l);
    }
    public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener l){other.addChangeListener(l);
    }
    public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener l){other.removeChangeListener(l);
    }
    public Object[] getSelectedObjects(){return other.getSelectedObjects();
    }
    }


    import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
    import javax.swing.JTree;
    import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent;
    import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener;
    import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

    public class CheckTreeManager extends MouseAdapter implements TreeSelectionListener{ 
    private CheckTreeSelectionModel selectionModel; 
    private JTree tree = new JTree(); 
    int hotspot = new JCheckBox().getPreferredSize().width; 

    public CheckTreeManager(JTree tree){ 
    this.tree = tree; 
    selectionModel = new CheckTreeSelectionModel(tree.getModel()); 
    tree.setCellRenderer(new CheckTreeCellRenderer(tree.getCellRenderer(), selectionModel)); 
    tree.addMouseListener(this); 
    selectionModel.addTreeSelectionListener(this); 
    } 

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me){ 
    TreePath path = tree.getPathForLocation(me.getX(), me.getY()); 
    if(path==null) 
    return; 
    if(me.getX()>tree.getPathBounds(path).x+hotspot) 
    return; 

    boolean selected = selectionModel.isPathSelected(path, true); 
    selectionModel.removeTreeSelectionListener(this); 

    try{ 
    if(selected) 
    selectionModel.removeSelectionPath(path); 
    else 
    selectionModel.addSelectionPath(path); 
    System.out.println("Tree Path :"+path);
    } finally{ 
        selectionModel.addTreeSelectionListener(this); 
        tree.treeDidChange(); 
    } 
    } 

    public CheckTreeSelectionModel getSelectionModel(){return selectionModel; 
    } 
    public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e){tree.treeDidChange(); 
    }
} 



    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TristateCheckBoxTest");     //NOI18N
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
    final TristateCheckBox swingBox = new TristateCheckBox(
            "Testing the tristate checkbox");  //NOI18N
    swingBox.setMnemonic('T');
    frame.getContentPane().add(swingBox);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    }


    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Stack;
    import javax.swing.tree.*;

    public class CheckTreeSelectionModel extends DefaultTreeSelectionModel{ 
    private TreeModel model; 
//FileTreeModel model;

    public CheckTreeSelectionModel(TreeModel model){ 
    this.model = model; 
    setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.DISCONTIGUOUS_TREE_SELECTION); 
    } 

    // tests whether there is any unselected node in the subtree of given path 
    public boolean isPartiallySelected(TreePath path){ 
    if(isPathSelected(path, true)) 
        return false; 
    TreePath[] selectionPaths = getSelectionPaths(); 
    if(selectionPaths==null) 
    return false; 
    for(int j = 0; j<selectionPaths.length; j++){ 
    if(isDescendant(selectionPaths[j], path)) 
    return true; 
    } 
    return false; 
    } 

    // tells whether given path is selected. 
    // if dig is true, then a path is assumed to be selected, if 
    // one of its ancestor is selected. 
    public boolean isPathSelected(TreePath path, boolean dig){ 
    if(!dig) 
       return super.isPathSelected(path); 
    while(path!=null && !super.isPathSelected(path)) 
    path = path.getParentPath(); 
    return path!=null; 
    } 

    // is path1 descendant of path2 
    private boolean isDescendant(TreePath path1, TreePath path2){ 
    Object obj1[] = path1.getPath(); 
    Object obj2[] = path2.getPath(); 
    for(int i = 0; i<obj2.length; i++){ 
    if(obj1[i]!=obj2[i]) 
    return false; 
    } 
    return true; 
    } 

    public void setSelectionPaths(TreePath[] pPaths){ 
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented yet!!!"); 
    } 

    public void addSelectionPaths(TreePath[] paths){ 
    // unselect all descendants of paths[] 
    for(int i = 0; i<paths.length; i++){ 
        TreePath path = paths[i]; 
        TreePath[] selectionPaths = getSelectionPaths(); 
        if(selectionPaths==null) 
            break; 
        ArrayList toBeRemoved = new ArrayList(); 
        for(int j = 0; j<selectionPaths.length; j++){ 
            if(isDescendant(selectionPaths[j], path)) 
                toBeRemoved.add(selectionPaths[j]); 
        } 
        super.removeSelectionPaths((TreePath[])toBeRemoved.toArray(new TreePath[0])); 
    } 

    // if all siblings are selected then unselect them and select parent recursively 
    // otherwize just select that path. 
    for(int i = 0; i<paths.length; i++){ 
        TreePath path = paths[i]; 
        TreePath temp = null; 
        while(areSiblingsSelected(path)){ 
            temp = path; 
            if(path.getParentPath()==null) 
                break; 
            path = path.getParentPath(); 
        } 
        if(temp!=null){ 
            if(temp.getParentPath()!=null) 
                addSelectionPath(temp.getParentPath()); 
            else{ 
                if(!isSelectionEmpty()) 
                    removeSelectionPaths(getSelectionPaths()); 
                super.addSelectionPaths(new TreePath[]{temp}); 
            } 
        }else 
            super.addSelectionPaths(new TreePath[]{ path}); 
      } 
    } 

    // tells whether all siblings of given path are selected. 
     private boolean areSiblingsSelected(TreePath path){ 
    TreePath parent = path.getParentPath(); 
    if(parent==null) 
        return true; 
    Object node = path.getLastPathComponent(); 
    Object parentNode = parent.getLastPathComponent(); 

    int childCount = model.getChildCount(parentNode); 
    for(int i = 0; i<childCount; i++){ 
        Object childNode = model.getChild(parentNode, i); 
        if(childNode==node) 
            continue; 
        if(!isPathSelected(parent.pathByAddingChild(childNode))) 
            return false; 
    } 
    return true; 
    } 

    public void removeSelectionPaths(TreePath[] paths){ 
    for(int i = 0; i<paths.length; i++){ 
        TreePath path = paths[i]; 
        if(path.getPathCount()==1) 
            super.removeSelectionPaths(new TreePath[]{ path}); 
        else 
            toggleRemoveSelection(path); 
    } 
   } 

   // if any ancestor node of given path is selected then unselect it 
     //  and selection all its descendants except given path and descendants. 
    // otherwise just unselect the given path 
     private void toggleRemoveSelection(TreePath path){ 
    Stack stack = new Stack(); 
    TreePath parent = path.getParentPath(); 
    while(parent!=null && !isPathSelected(parent)){ 
        stack.push(parent); 
        parent = parent.getParentPath(); 
    } 
    if(parent!=null) 
        stack.push(parent); 
    else{ 
        super.removeSelectionPaths(new TreePath[]{path}); 
        return; 
    } 

    while(!stack.isEmpty()){ 
        TreePath temp = (TreePath)stack.pop(); 
        TreePath peekPath = stack.isEmpty() ? path : (TreePath)stack.peek(); 
        Object node = temp.getLastPathComponent(); 
        Object peekNode = peekPath.getLastPathComponent(); 
        int childCount = model.getChildCount(node); 
        for(int i = 0; i<childCount; i++){ 
            Object childNode = model.getChild(node, i); 
            if(childNode!=peekNode) 
                super.addSelectionPaths(new TreePath[]  {temp.pathByAddingChild(childNode)}); 
       } 
       } 
    super.removeSelectionPaths(new TreePath[]{parent}); 
    } 
   }
```

Comment: Please clean up the code so it's organized and easy to read. In addition, simplify the code so that your issue is clearly highlighted rather than your entire program.

Comment: Alos consider [`org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692).

Comment: And what exactly is the problem ? Since you can create a `TreeModel` for one drive, adjusting that code to support multiple drives is rather straight forward. So I am unsure what exactly is your problem

Comment: @ Robin, Sir I have tried to do that adjustment as the following code but its not working.     
   for(File root: roots)
   {
    model=new FileTreeModel(root);
    tree.setModel(model);
   }
  
  //  model = new FileTreeModel(roots[0]);
  // tree.setModel(model); but its not working if you can please let me what and where i should do modification. I know its very silly question but sir i am beginner for java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**put following code in the main in comment and run it again then you will see where is problem and start to debug it.**

```
  CheckTreeManager checkTreeManager = new CheckTreeManager(tree);
    TreePath checkedPaths[]=checkTreeManager.getSelectionModel().getSelectionPaths();
    int j = checkedPaths.length;
    System.out.println("Tree Path :"+j);

    for(int i=0; i<checkedPaths.length;i++){
        System.out.println("Tree Path :"+checkedPaths[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for ur kind information but i need the solution. the modification that i think is required in fileTreeModel class. fileTreeModel is designed for  File type object but it should be modified for File array so can take the File array that having the all root and then construct the model accordingly but i am not very familiar with the language so i m not able to do that correction. Please help me out thank u