# How to create file-chooser

Tags: swing, file-io, filesystems

How to create file-chooser that can select multiple derives/folders/files at a time as bellow figure example. I want to use checkbox for selecting items and the drive which are not available at the time of choosing the should be disable like gray mark for H, I, Z derives n fig. [image]

Comment: What have you tried so far, in this nice endeavour of yours. Had you tried your hands on [JTree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html)

Comment: You should've added the Link to your [code that you had tried here with this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10058918/1057230)

Answer (score 1):

There is no default component which looks like the one in your screenshot. You would have to build that by yourself.

Have a look at [JTrees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) and use a custom TreeRenderer which uses JCheckboxes to display the nodes. You can then enable/disable specific nodes, and get a list of all selected ones

Comment: thanks u can have a look at my another question "How to create a JTree with JCheckbox to Show Systems All drives and its Folders/Files" there i have given code that i have tried to do but problem is that this code is fine for creating tree for 1 drive but not for all. I have tried by looping to create for all but i dint get success please see the code and suggest me where and what i have to modify..